# At what level should I start praying to Inconsequentia?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Inconsequentia, the Goddest of Sidequests, can grant [quests](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Sidequest) leading to random artifacts. I've tried her twice on two fresh characters; both times, the quest was about killing a horribly out of depth baddie that was just lurking behind the door and had little trouble disposing of me.

When should I pray to Incosequentia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the first floor, I generally just pray whenever I see the statue - the quest is either going to be trivial (ie, go find an item or put this item with the shrine) or hard (kill this special monster or an army of regular monsters) and the difficulty of the quest doesn't change much with respect to how long you've been on a floor.

On the first floor, I might take a few character levels first, as you'll likely gain several levels just exploring the floor, and levels are relatively cheap.  When you stop being beaten half to death by every bat and blob that shows up, you'll know you're ready.

Even if you clear the whole level like Oak suggests, monsters will slowly respawn.  The random nature of the quest, coupled with the random nature of the floor, and the random nature of the game in general, mean that things can go from very good to very bad extremely quickly, with or without the quest.

I'd focus on glitching, trapping, or debuffing the AI (ie, sticking them in a spot where they can't get to you, fighting near a Glyph/door,  or rooting them in place) to give your hero a bit longer to mash on them before they can do damage to you.

And remember, Dying is Fun!

Answer (score 3):

The safest way is to pray after you've cleared the whole floor. That way you'll usually have very little, if any, regular mobs near the quest-specific ones.

But don't neglect her! Her rewards are usually pretty decent items.

Answer (score 0):

I pray whenever I see the statue. Otherwise I have to revisit the whole dungeon level to find the baddies and it is rather time consuming.

Most of my builds include conjuration ( not sure this is the right name ) to summon Mr Mustache. It makes the early levels much easier.

Also, by the time you reach Dredmor, it is very unlikely that you would have leveled all your skill trees to the max so taking this skill just for the early levels is not much of a waste.